# How to compare two checkbox arrays in WordPress admin

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a front-end form submitting to my custom post type and checkboxes within. 

`<input type="checkbox" name="_my_checkbox[]" value="Yes"/> Yes
<input type="checkbox" name="_my_checkbox[]" value="No"/> No
<input type="checkbox" name="_my_checkbox[]" value="Maybe"/> Maybe`

After that I saved it as post meta.
Then I need admin handling for this posts and values. As far as I've tried only accomplished to save and manipulate one value. I guess the problem is somewhere within the arrays.
Here it is a part of the function which displays the meta box.

`$get_my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta', true); 
 $get_my_meta_data = array('Yes','No','Maybe');`

```
        foreach ($get_my_meta_data as $key => $value) { ?>

          <input type="checkbox" name="_admin_my_checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>"<?php if($value == $get_my_meta){echo 'checked';} ?> /><?php echo $value;

        }`
```

And then comes the saving function

```
if($_POST['_admin_my_checkbox']) {

        $my_checkbox_updater = $_POST['_admin_my_checkbox'];
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_meta', $my_checkbox_updater);    

    }
```

In this case when I check some of the checkboxes and use `print_r` values are saved as expected. I guess the problem is within `foreach` loop but have no idea what could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick edit. Found solution. `in_array()` function do the job perfectly.

```
foreach ($get_my_meta_data as $key => $value) { ?>

      <input type="checkbox" name="_admin_my_checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>"<?php if(in_array($value,$get_my_meta)){echo 'checked';} ?> /><?php echo $value;

    }
```